# Not able to find Team Signing Requests

Tags: iphone, ios, provisioning

I just sent a request to my team member for joining "Apple Developer Program". He approved my request and he got the access to dev center. When he uploaded CSR of his Mac, he got his certificate status **Submitted**. And I also got email for **Certificate Request Requires Your Approval** But when I clicked the link of Provisioning Portal and proceed to certificates section, I couldn't find his certificate on "**Team Signing Requests (0)**".  The **Signing Requests** list to approve his certificate is empty.

Please let me know if I am missing any important part of this team member creation process? And FYI, that team member may already joined with other developer programs.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: may be its e-mail id (if already associated with apple) that causes the problem.